# Exit.Strategy Conditional Comment

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to work out if there is an in-line way to get strategy.exit comments to be conditional - int he main for the comment to state if stop or limit has been triggered.

essentially some code that sits where XXXXX. is below which will output "Stop" or "Limit" based on the exit triggering.

```
strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=stopLossB, limit=takeProfitB, comment = XXXXXXXXXX)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `comment_profit` and `comment_loss` arguments for that.

> ***comment_profit (series string)*** Additional notes on the order if the
> exit was triggered by crossing `profit` or `limit` specifically. If
> specified, supercedes the `comment` parameter and displays near the
> order marker on the chart. Optional. The default is na.
>
> ***comment_loss (series string)*** Additional notes on the order if the exit
> was triggered by crossing `stop` or `loss` specifically. If specified,
> supercedes the `comment` parameter and displays near the order marker
> on the chart. Optional. The default is na.

Or you can prepare the string yourself.

For a long position:

```
is_limit_hit = (high >= takeProfitB)
is_stop_hit = (low <= stopLossB)
my_comment = is_limit_hit ? "Limit" : is_stop_hit ? "Stop" : "None"
```